# in Gradle, how can I tell which task was created by which plugin?

Tags: gradle

I want to print only the tasks that I have in my script, with their dependencies, and separately the tasks created by some plugins.
I could not find a way to do it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Rather not possible. `Plugin` doesn't have (according to API) a collection of tasks it adds. The same is with `Task`, it doesn't have a reference to plugin it belongs to.

What you can do is to configure `group` property for each task you add and try to discriminate tasks using the name of the group added.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [gradle-taskinfo](https://gitlab.com/barfuin/gradle-taskinfo#gradle-taskinfo) plugin.

It prints the tasks, and task dependencies, plus the class names of each task. It does not show the plugin that created a task, because Gradle doesn't remember that. But the class name often gives a pretty good hint at which plugin it might have been.

Example:

```
$ ./gradlew tiTree assemble

:assemble                             (org.gradle.api.DefaultTask)
+--- :jar                             (org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar)
|    `--- :classes                    (org.gradle.api.DefaultTask)
|         +--- :compileJava           (org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile)
|         `--- :processResources      (org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources)
+--- :javadocJar                      (org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar)
|    `--- :javadoc                    (org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc)
|         `--- :classes               (org.gradle.api.DefaultTask)
|              +--- :compileJava      (org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile)
|              `--- :processResources (org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources)
`--- :sourcesJar                      (org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar)
```

Full disclosure: I am the author of gradle-taskinfo. It's free and open-source.